# Linux debian8 OpenVPN

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

i have a VPS with debian8 installed, I have successfully installed openvpn, 
I want my home computer to be able to connect to the VPN server encrypting the traffic but I still need the orginal IP to be visible.
The option to use MASQUERADE is not feasible.
 the schema is very simple but still I can't have it work.

Public internet ------VPS-eth0--- VPN network 10.0.8.0/24 ----- Home pc

any help ? 
thanks 
Roberto

Comment: How do you want to distinguish which internet packets go over the VPN, and which packets go over the "visible" original IP? You can only set one default route.

Comment: Hi, allora the traffico should have visibile IP.